# How to identify table of two different servers

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different servers. I have written the code to fetch the table from two different servers. I have common name table in both servers. How can I identify from which server this table belongs?

```
$conn1 = mysql_connect($server1.':'.$port1,$user1,$pass1); 
$list1 = mysql_list_dbs($conn1); 
$select = '<select name="dbone">'; 
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($list1)) { 
   $select.='<option value="'.$row1->Database.'">'.$row1->Database.'</option>';
} 
$select.='</select>'; 
echo $select; 

$conn2 = mysql_connect($server2.':'.$port2,$user2,$pass2); 
$list2 = mysql_list_dbs($conn2); 
$select = '<select name="dbtwo">';  
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($list2)) { 
   $select.='<option value="'.$row2->Database.'">'.$row2->Database.'</option>';
} 
$select.='</select>'; 
echo $select;
```

Comment: $conn1   = mysql_connect($server1.':'.$port1,$user1,$pass1);
$list1   = mysql_list_dbs($conn1);
$select  = '<select name="dbone">';
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($list1)) {
 $select.='<option value="'.$row1->Database.'">'.$row1->Database.'</option>';
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select;
$conn2   = mysql_connect($server2.':'.$port2,$user2,$pass2);
$list2    = mysql_list_dbs($conn2);
$select  = '<select name="dbtwo">';
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($list2)) {
     $select.='<option value="'.$row2->Database.'">'.$row2->Database.'</option>';
}
$select.='</select>';
echo $select;

Answer (score 1):

So as per your code you have two connection

Following is code

```
<?php 
$sql = "show tables";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$g8_cone);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sql = "show tables";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$g8_ctwo);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

you will get list all table from that both server.

thanks 
Pratik

Comment: see I have table name cfg in both servers, in  same name databases in server1 and server2 but its not printing from which server it belongs even i have tried your code.